# How can I make JShell stop wrapping lines back on themselves?

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, jline, jshell, jline2

I'm using *JDK 9* build 179 on *Windows 7*. I've got the "*Screen Buffer Size Width*" property of my *Windows 7* command shell, set to a large number because that's the way I roll. That works fine normally; when I'm simply using the *Windows* shell on its own.

Unfortunately though, when I'm using *JShell*, my "*Screen Buffer Size Width*" property is ignored and *JShell* wraps my long lines back on themselves. When a line wraps, it doesn't create a new line. Instead, the cursor doubles back to the beginning  of the same line and overwrites characters in that line.

[*Take a look at this screen recording to see what I mean*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1jDQ.jpg).

It appears to be using the rightmost dimension of the actual width of the window as its cue to wrap a line; ignoring the "*Screen Buffer Size Width*" property. That property's sole purpose in life is to explicitly prevent wrapping and allow long lines up to a maximum of 9999 characters.

I've put up with [*this annoying crap*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1jDQ.jpg) since *JDK 9 ea+166*. I patiently waited for months; expecting it would be fixed by the time of *JDK 9*'s general release. No such luck.

Please, can anybody let me in on the secret of [*how to fix this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1jDQ.jpg)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you report this to the [mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo)?

Comment: Seems like all you have to do now is post a simple message on the mailing list and reference this post.  But I might suggest you tone down your anger just a bit.

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer. I'll get on that right away. The only thing I could find before you shared [_your link_](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo), was [_the Open JDK Bug System_](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8157261); which isn't open to the public I don't think. I'd planned on reporting it in [_Oracle's Java Bugs Database_](https://www.oracle.com/search/results?Ntt=jshell%20wraps%20lines&Dy=1&Nty=1&cat=bugs&Ntk=S3) but I wanted to check here in SO first; so as not to go off half-cocked. Thanks for [_the mailing list link_](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo).

Comment: "_Anger_" @JimGarrison? Who's "_angry_"? That's just how we talk where I come from. We say crap like "_crap_" all the time—with a smile on our faces and a sing-songy song in our hearts ;)

Comment: @nullpointer I tried emailing to [_Open JDK's jdk9-dev mailing-list_](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/jdk9-dev) from my unregistered email address. They snubbed me! And after the stress of jumping through first SO's and then imgur's sign-up hoops to post my findings here, I wasn't in the mood for an uber elitist ezmlm mailing list subscription process. Instead, I went ahead and [_submitted it as a bug to Oracle_](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8191640); it's their product after all. I didn't even need to login or register! That's what I call "_Service_"!

Answer (score 2):

Since [*Oracle has officially confirmed that the issue I discovered is indeed a bug*](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8191640), my own answer for this question is, "[*Use BeanShell's Interactive Console instead*](http://beanshell.org)".

[*bsh*](http://beanshell.org) has met all my personal Java REPL needs unfailingly for going on eight or ten years now. There's nothing that I currently use jshell for that I can't also do in [*bsh*](http://beanshell.org); with a lot more ease and a lot more intuitively, in my opinion.

Sure, jshell does a couple things that [*bsh*](http://beanshell.org) doesn't do. But if like me all you use a Java REPL for is to try out code on the command line, then [*bsh*](http://beanshell.org) can't be beat as an already-mature Java REPL option; tried and proven by thousands (*if not millions*) of developers over a lotta years ([*since 1999, in fact*](http://web.archive.org/web/19990915000000*/http://www.beanshell.org:80/)).